# Unix scripting for servces to check

Tags: unix

I am struggling to write a script to check a particular service running on my server and then send me mails.
So should this script be the part of bash profile so that its always running..

regards
rick

Comment: Search about [cron](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html)

Answer (score 0):

The .profile, .bashrc and friends will be run on login, so they are of no good use for background monitoring. Two solutions come to mind:

- Either use `cron` to run your script at predefined intervals
- Or make it loop and use your system's init environment (SysV, Upstart, SystemD, ...) to control it

My recommendation is to stick with `cron` - it even makes the mailing of results dead easy - just create output.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/ksh
if echo "GET; exit" | mconnect -p 80 xx.xx.xx.xx > /dev/null 2>&1 
 then 
  exit 0
 else
  echo "Please check Web services " | mailx -s "Please check http" emailaddress@xyzcom
  exit 1
fi